# WatchOS app running in background

Tags: apple-watch, watchos

How to keep apple watch app running in background.
I build a timer, but every time screen dims and I wake up the app it resets the timer. How to avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're supposed to.

Apple specifically [say](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/iOSSupport.html):

> - **Do not use background execution modes for a technology.** Watch apps are considered foreground apps because they run only while the user interacts with one of their interfaces. As a result, the corresponding WatchKit extension cannot take advantage of most background execution modes to perform tasks.

You might want to [check elapsed time on wakeup](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/21025) instead.